# How can my app facilitate a message to multiple friends?

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app that needs to allow a user to send a message to multiple friends (potentially all their friends) at once.  This isn't any kind of spam, and I don't need the app to send the message incognito (behind the scenes), I just need to open a dialog with specific friends pre-populated (that the user has selected within my app in a prior step) and then send them a custom message.  Is this possible? I see the api for sending a message to a single friend, and I see the API for inviting users to my app (but that's limited to some very small number of invitations per day)... what I need is a dialog that lets me send messages to as many of the user's friends as they want, but for me to control *which friends are selected... I don't want to give them control to add/remove from the friends list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Send Dialog allows prefilling only a single friend, but would otherwise be the best option here if you need a custom message displayed to the recipient. You could get the user to send to several friends in a loop by prefilling this - or fire the dialog without prefilling and let the user chose who to send to - your app won't receive a callback with the recipient IDs but you could put a referrer param in the URL sent?

Failing that, the Requests dialog / 'invites' are the only thing you can prefill with multiple recipients without the expectation that your app will be shut down for spam shortly thereafter - there's no limit per day on the number of requests sent, but you don't get to set the message shown to the recipient.

Comment: there's "no" limit per day? I thought there was... did they remove that constraint?

Comment: The old limits were removed in February 2011 when Requests '2.0' was launched - Currently there's a 50 requests per dialog-instance limit definitely. There could be a max requests per day limit too, but if there is i'm not aware of it and it's above 50 per user per day

Answer (score 0):

In case this is helpful to anyone else, I just found this... it's a relatively new API (still in beta) that allows for (just about) exactly what I was asking for. I've tested it and it appears to work...
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/31/reach-users-1-1-with-the-notifications-api/